# Issue with routes in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

facing a strange situation in laravel 5.2
The project is hosted on godaddy with shared hosting plan.
I've already defined few routes in routes.php and all are working fine.
Recently I've added 3 more under auth middleware, and now those 3 new routes are not working on server. However they're working fine on my localhost. Triple checked the routes.php on server and the code is there.

```
Route::get('contact','ContactusController@index');
```

This url is giving following error :

```
NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:
```

and the url mentioned above / below those lines are working fine.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Run `php artisan route:clear`.

Comment: Can you show the complete `routes.php` file? Did you upload the updated `ContactusController` file?

Comment: @TheFallen, it worked, thanks.

Comment: Would be nice if @TheFallen could add an answer explaining what he think the problem was and why that worked to get this matter closed (so an unanswered question doesn't stay just sitting there).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OP probably cached his routes using `route:cache`on the production server, so any changes will require him to clear the route cache via `php artisan route:clear` for the new changes to take effect.

Pros to route caching: Sitespeed gets faster
Cons to route caching: Requires to re-cache every time a change is made so its usually only done so on a production server.

Comment: Interestingly enough, I could setup my CI tool to run `php artisan route:clear` everytime a new build is being pulled and it would get this problem solved automatically.